# How to add multiple rows with one query in android using parse.com

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I want to add 30 rows with one query to my table at parse.com. Since parse gives limited API requests. I have stored 30 values in my arraylist and want to create separate rows for each value in my table. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/save-multiple-objects-with-one-request-on-android)

> You can use the saveAllInBackground static method of ParseObject. You
>   pass in a list of ParseObjects you wish to save. You can look at the
>   API reference docs for more details:
>   http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveAllInBackground(java.util.List)

So I'll assume you have 30 ParseObjects that belong in the same table, then the saveAllInBackground(); should work